# Can Fancytree be configured to stay collapsed when an item is dragged and dropped to a parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I am working in a tool that uses Fancytree for lists.  Currently when I drag and drop an item to nest it, the parent item will expand.  I'd like to turn this off so that Fancytree remains in whatever state it's in. I've got a minimal coding background, but know enough that I think I can find the setting if I know what I am looking for.

I've searched though the various files and tried to find the specific behavior configurations but so far, the changes I have made and tested have not resolved it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be looking for the [dnd5.autoExpandMS](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/ExtDnd5#usage) option.
Pass `0` to disable automatic expansion on hover.

Comment: Thanks so much!  This seems more inline with what I am looking for.  I'll poke around and see if I can find that in the files.

Comment: That got the first problem solved and set me on the path to fix the rest. I also changed "node.setExpanded(true).always(function () {
                        // Wait until expand finished, then add the additional child
                        data.otherNode.moveTo(node, data.hitMode);" to 'false' and that took care of the auto expand on the drop.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To properly use Fancytree, you will need to adjust settings such as your web browser, operating system, and user interface. Note that these instructions may vary depending on the version of your software or browser.
For most users, adjusting their web browsers is the easiest way to get started. You can usually find detailed instructions in the help section of your browser or online support forum. For example, if you are using Chrome OS and want to use Fancytree with a Google Docs document: 1) open a new window in which you'll be working on the document 2) click File > Make A Copy 3) switch to the original document's tab 4) right-click anywhere inside it and select "Open In New Frame" 5) copy/paste this address into Your Browser://localhost:8081/?settings=chrome&ulimitstartuptime=0 6). After opening this link (Your Browser://localhost:8081/?settings=chrome), press Enter 7). Select "Use Default Settings for This Window." 8). Close all other windows 9) return to fancytree 10)).

Comment: You could just edit your previous answer instead of posting a new one. Did you see [answer] already?